# Which version of Git is used with Maven Release Plugin?

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, maven-release-plugin

I have a freestyle job in jenkins on which I'm running : `mvn release:prepare` and `mvn release:perform`, on a slave which have a specific path to git on its configuration(/$HOME/tools/git/bin). I have troubles with git, I want to know which git is used for doing git add, commit and push that are used when doing release commands. I didn't specify in my pom file `org.apache.maven.scm`. Is it using the default git ? (output if which git (/usr/local/git/bin)).

Comment: Can you specify the problem you are having? There is a well known bug in older release plugin versions which you might have. It causes the changes in the poms not to be committed/pushed.

Comment: git add command fails. This is due to git installation which is not correct, I need to point to an other version of git on the machine (linux). May be the problem will be: how to point git on an other version :  how to change the output of "which git". But here my question is that I wanted to understand which version of git maven uses. the one by default returned by (which git) or the one specified in the slave configuration on jenkins ?

Comment: Ok that's a different problem then. Anyway, make sure to use the newest release plugin to avoid other problems.

Comment: execute shell in your jenkins job and print `git --version`. The git installation on Jenkins is managed in the global tool config